# Reverse Geocoding Remote Islands

Tags: reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to reverse geocode remote islands in the south pacific. All works well with the country name and admin area but the island name is not coming through. Is there anyway to get island names using the google maps api (or any other free/low cost service)? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, followed the link from google maps api and did not think. So, currently I am looking into google maps api using json and also the geonames web service. I am open to any free/low cost service.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/

Comment: Seemed google maps specific, but obliviously it was not.

Comment: Islands in south pacific. Which country (or countries) do these islands belong to, would you know?

Comment: yes, both Fiji and Vanuatu

Answer (score 1):

In short: I'm afraid there is no easy way.

Reverse geocoding in the Google Geocoding API will return the political entities that contain the given latlng, but physical entities such as islands may not align well with these.

Fiji and Vanuatu have their own ISO 3166-2 region codes (often called "country codes"), so any latlng in them should return the islands themselves as the "country" address component (or last result in the list):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-17.713371,178.065032
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-15.376706,166.959158

In Hawaii, the big islands give name to their counties (administrative_area_level_2), but the smaller ones don't.
I'm not familiar with many islands in the Pacific, but the above already illustrates there is no support for "island" results. You might get it to work if your scope is narrow (a small set of islands) and the islands there align well with political divisions.